# What happens to char round-trip cast through a bool?

Tags: c++, casting, boolean, language-lawyer, roundtrip

What does the C++ language definition promise about casting a char to bool then back to char again?

```
char original = 255;
bool next = original;
char final = next;
```

Also, what do most compilers do in this case beyond what the language guarantees?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will give a value of zero or one, depending on whether the original value was zero or non-zero.

Converting to `bool` gives a value of `true` or `false`:

> 4.12 A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`.

Converting back to `char` converts `false` to zero, and `true` to one:

> 4.7/4 If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and
>   the value `true` is converted to one.

Answer (score 3):

Integral values converted to `bool` result in either `true` or `false` (4.12), and `bool` converted to integral values results in either `1` or `0` (4.5(6)). See Chapter 4 (Standard Conversions).

Answer (score 2):

When converting to bool zero and null are converted to false, and everything else is converted to true. When converting from bool false is converted to zero and true is converted to one.